# get the value that is inside an input tag

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

How can I get the value, if it resides inside the input tag using phantomjs, javascript and DOM?

Here is how it looks like:

```
<input name="__Token" type="hidden" value="OhG2aIRUXlWOZ4XlP89Uc21p8gv3N2V5laChqwYox086Xfyp‌​jTyXK-cAGKpJCPO1Cb83‌​lC_0ju2yAzXYoOasFyBD‌​P6wMN82K5WRcOKguTTYK‌​AI_rvedwhedWtXjixiq4‌​h8IhKqZrczyQvUdKzWYe‌​5tarAXu-gejJhs1gF0mC‌​cZo1">
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, or just looking for a handout?

Comment: You do exactly what you put in your question. You use javascript to access the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = document.querySelector('input[name="__Token"]').value;
```

Comment: You can mark it as the accepted answer if this is what you think the best solution is then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct then to get value of input with name "__Token" you should use this code:

```
var value = document.getElementsByName('__Token')[0].value;
```

Comment: This one doesn't work. It gives me null. I have tried it many times.

Comment: @Puzzle Nobody knows you tried that "many times" because your original question is not very detailed.

Comment: @Puzzle Works for me, check your syntax. I personally prefer TW80000's answer, but both work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
  var arr = document.getElementsByName("__Token")[0].getAttribute('value');
  alert(arr);
```

http://jsbin.com/dadugikexa/edit?html,js,console,output